# RPG.SE has admitted its first Hobgoblin to the 100k club

Tags: discussion, reputation, just-for-fun, users

Please join me in congratulating [Nobody the Hobgoblin](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/75095/nobody-the-hobgoblin) (formerly Groody) for reaching 100,000 reputation!

[image]

Notably, Nobody the Hobgoblin is the quickest user to ever reach 100k reputation, having done so in less than two years.

Thanks for your contributions, and here’s to another 100k!

Comment: Congratulations!

Comment: Congratulations!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Thank you, all of you!

First, thank you Thomas for calling this out -- nothing escapes your eagle eye.

Thank you, to all of you who have been welcoming, supportive, gracious and patient with my antics. And above all, thank you for those of you who have enriched my understanding of the game with your wonderful answers to my questions.